# Write to File on server is not working, permission issue?

Tags: php

I have the very simple following php file:

```
<p>1 Some HTML, I am not losing my mind</p>
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

When executed on command line, everything is perfectly fine, data is write to file.
When I try to execute it on firefox browser, I saw the "Some HTML, I am not losing my mind" comment appears but nothing is written on the server.

Is this a permission issue? I am using ubuntu for server. Files are in public_html directory that has following permission:

```
bomble@ChemAlive:~$ ls -la public_html
total 24
drwxrwxr-x  4 bomble bomble 4096 Feb 18 11:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 bomble bomble 4096 Feb 18 09:42 ..
drwxr-xr-x 12 bomble bomble 4096 Feb 16 13:43 Website
-rw-rw-r--  1 bomble bomble   18 Feb 18 11:19 newfile.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 bomble bomble  232 Feb 18 11:19 process.php
drwxrwxr-x  2 bomble bomble 4096 Feb 18 11:22 test
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: How did you called your script over the browser? via `file:///` ?

Comment: Probably your web server user doesnt have permissions to write to that file. Adjust permissions accordingly

Comment: Well, it didn’t die() or you would have seen that text. So, why are you not testing the result of open() (or using http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)?  

Bad coder, bad! No pizza for you!

Comment: @Rizier123 I call the script via http. http://http://192.168.1.102/~bomble/test/process.php

Comment: Bad web coder I agree! I am a C++ girl.... who start for the first time to set up a server and a website. So yes I need help! I am such a newbie that I don't know how to adjust the permission of my web server user!

Comment: I am making process. Thus I read a bit apache doc and realized I shouldn't be things anywhere on my server bu in correct dir as /var/www/html .... sorry for being such a newbie. Thus now when I display my php in the bromser it is saying this ` 1 Some HTML, you are not losing your mind
Unable to open file` thus not working but better!

Comment: This is really a permission issue. If I create the file I want to write in and allow everyone to write on it and then execute it through the browser, thinks are working.